Is there a formula for the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[\chi_{A}|\mathcal B]$?
Background:
$(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space and $\mathcal B$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field,that is $\mathcal B\subset \mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$ field.
Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $[0, \infty]$.There exists a $\mathcal{B}$-measurable random variable with values in $[0, \infty]$, denoted by $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{B}]$, such that, for every nonnegative $\mathcal B$-measurable random variable $Z$,
$$\mathbb{E}[X\cdot Z]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{B}]\cdot Z].$$
Furthermore $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{B}]$ is unique up to a $\mathcal B$-measurable set of probability zero.
Question:

Let $A\in \mathcal A$,then $\chi_{A}$( characteristic function of $A$) is a random variable. Can we have a simple formula for $\mathbb E[\chi_{A}|\mathcal B]$?
The question is equivalent to finding a random variable such that:$$\forall B\in \mathcal B, \mathbb E[\chi_{A}\cdot \chi_{B}]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\chi_A|\mathcal B]\cdot \chi_B]$$


No. There is no such formula.

When $\cal B$ is finite there is.

Since $\chi_A$ is manifestly $L^2$, you can also say that $E[\chi_A\mid \mathcal B]$ is the projection of $\chi_A$, as an element of $L^2(X,\mathcal A,\Bbb P)$, onto the closed subspace $L^2(X,\mathcal B,\Bbb P)$.

So if you manage to find a Hilbert basis ${e_k}{k\in\Bbb N}$ of $L^2(X,\mathcal B,\Bbb P)$, then you can write $E[\chi_A\mid \mathcal B]=\sum{k=1}^\infty e_k\int_A e_k,d\Bbb P$. (hope I didn't mess up the formula)

@KurtG., I think it is sufficient, but not necessary. If $\mathcal H=(H_i){i\in\Bbb N}$ where $(H_i){i\in\Bbb N}$ form a partition of $\Omega$ and $\Bbb P(H_i)>0,\forall i\in\Bbb N$, $\sigma(\mathcal H)$ consists of countable unions of sets from $\mathcal H$ and $$\Bbb E[X\mid\mathcal H]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\Bbb E[X\chi_{H_i}]}{\Bbb P(H_i)}\chi_{H_i}.$$ See.

If I were to close this question, I would put being duplicate as the reason for closure. I find needs more focus more vague than the question itself is as I believe I've understood the OP troubles immediatelly.

One needs a countable family of mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive events, all with positive probability.

@CherryBlossom sufficient. Is it necessary?

@KurtG., just sufficient, but I think it covers a wider range of possible $\mathcal B$'s.

@CherryBlossom correct. This could be an answer that is not a duplicate.

The definitions, lemma, and theorem are from Mathematical Statistics by Prof. M. Huzak, Faculty of Science, University of Zagreb.
Definition 2.11. Let $Y$ be a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \Bbb P)$ such that $\Bbb E[|Y|] < +\infty$, and let $\mathcal G $ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal F$. A random variable $\hat Y$ satisfying the following properties:

$\hat Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable,
$\Bbb E[|\hat Y|]<+\infty$,
For all $G\in\mathcal G$,
$$\int_G\hat Y\, d\Bbb P=\int_G Y \, d\mathbb P,$$

is called a version of the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $\mathcal G$, and we denote it by $\Bbb E[Y\mid \mathcal G]$.

Lemma 2.12. For an event $B\in \mathcal F$ such that $\Bbb P(B)>0$ and $Y\in L^1$, it holds that:
$$\Bbb E[Y \mid B]=\frac{\Bbb E[Y\cdot \mathbf 1_B]}{\Bbb P(B)}.$$

Theorem 2.13. Let $\mathcal H=\{H_1,H_2,\dots\}$ be a countable partition of $\Omega$ into measurable sets, and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal G= \sigma(\mathcal H)$, and $Y \in L^1$. Then:
$$\Bbb E[Y\mid\mathcal G]=\sum_{k\ge 1}\Bbb E[Y\mid H_k]\cdot\mathbf 1_{H_k}.$$

To address the OP's question, it is sufficient to find a countable partition $\mathcal H=(H_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ of $\Omega$ s. t. $\Bbb P(H_i)>0,\forall i\in\Bbb N$. Then, $$\Bbb E[X\mid\sigma(\mathcal H)]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\Bbb E[X\mathbf 1_{H_i}]}{\Bbb P(H_i)}\mathbf 1_{H_i}.$$ In other words, it is sufficient if your sub-$\sigma$-algebra is generated by countably many mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive events, all of positive probabilities.
